# Data is not updated accordint to related props value

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use vuejs to have a modal window and hide it on putton pressed.
Here is some code:
**index.html**:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr v-for = "dream in dreams">
  ...
  <th>
    <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">New Post</button>
  </th>
  </tr>
</table>
...   

<editdream v-bind:show.sync="showModal"></editdream>
```

in editdream.vue file I have:

```
<template>
  <div v-show="isShown" transition="modal">
  ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  props: ['show'],
  methods: {

    close: function () {
        this.isShown = false;
    },

    savePost: function () {
        this.close();
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return { isShown: this.show }
  }
}
```

I supposed that when I press button then 'show' props will be updated for modal window and corresponding 'isShown' data will be udpdated as well. But I can only see that prop is becoming true, but isShown is still false when I press button. Could you please explain why?

Comment: This was a well written question. The only improvements I would recommend are mentioning a thing or two you have tried to fix the issue. Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Please tell us what VueJS version you are using - `sync` modifier on `v-bind` is deprecated in Vue 2

Comment: Thanks for the comments, soltuion is found I used "computed" instead of data. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `editdream.vue`, you've defined `isShown` in under `data`.

[`data` is set **once** prior to the creation of the component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), so it doesn't update when you click your `show-modal` button in `index.html`. `isShown` stays at whatever your prop `show` was set to on creation, prior to the button being clicked (presumably `false`).

A simple fix would be make `isShown` a [`computed` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad):

```
<template>
  <div v-show="isShown" transition="modal">
  ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['show'],
  methods: {
    close: function () {
        this.isShown = false;
    },
    savePost: function () {
        this.close();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isShown: function() return {this.show};
  }
}
```

computed properties actively watch the data on `this`, like your `show` prop, so it should update whenever `show` does.

Comment: Ok, great! 
I used "computed" to receive data from parent about was the button pressed and used "emit" to send the event that the modal window is closed to parent. Hope that this is how it should be done in correct way :)